# Why does my refurbished Nikon S3100 reject a new SD card with "this card cannot be used"?

Tags: nikon, troubleshooting, sdcard, error

New refurbished Nikon S3100 with new SD card shows error code ("this card cannot be used".) It is the correct card, also. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

There is a tab on the card that locks it from being written.  Make sure that's not in the wrong position.  Try moving it out of the lock position and see if it then works.

Otherwise try formatting it in camera, and if it won't format, try formatting the card on your computer using a card reader.

Comment: The step following that would be to try a different card (nobody's QA is absolutely perfect, and there are "black run" cards with convincing packaging that have hit the market). If that doesn't work, it's very likely a ribbon cable in the camera body not seated properly (a quick fix for a competent tech).

Comment: I'll add that if/when you format it using your computer, make sure you use one of the FAT file systems.